# Trying to install Kali

Tags: linux

I have a windows 8.1 HP laptop and I want to make it dual boot with Kali Linux but can't set the bootable flag to on when setting up the partition.

It snaps to a progress bar, then snaps back to the screen still saying "Bootable flag: off"

Edit: sorted it

Comment: There's no need to do any of that, just boot and install in UEFI mode. But if you don't know that already then definitely Kali isn't for you. As a matter of fact, Kali isn't to be installed at all (it can but it's designed to work mostly in a live session) and it's NOT a desktop Linux distro for daily usage. Choose Ubuntu or variants for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Kali should be properly used as a live distro, but if you do want to install it in a dual boot configuration with Windows 8.1, you first should create partitions with your terminal or partition editor and format them prior to using the Kali installer, rather than using the partition editor within the installer (which sucks honestly).

I assume you’ve turned Secure Boot off, right? Also, to address your previous concern about the bootable flag, your computer, if it is Windows 8.1 Certified, must have UEFI/GPT. This means you have an EFI System Partition which is marked as bootable. Usually it’s at the start of the drive/the first partition on the disk and is rather small, around 100 MB usually. Your system must not have a bootable flag set on any other partition but this EFI system partition.
DO NOT FORMAT THE EFI SYSTEM PARTITION. It will render your Windows installation unbootable.

I use GParted (I like Debian rather than Kali), and there’s a flags option there, and there should be a flag on “esp” and “boot” for this first partition.

After you create your partitions prior to the installation, go to manual partitioning options and EFI will already be used for you. You only need to mount the root partition and whatever other partitions you may have (like /home, /var, etc.) You should now be able to proceed with the installation without the flags problem.